# Cassandra chat app: sorting rooms after last message inserted

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0, cql3

For a messaging app I have a database structure comparatively to:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users(
    userid text,
    name text, 
    rooms list<text>
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (userid)
);

CREATE TABLE rooms(
    roomid text,
    members list<text>,
    createdat bigint,
    lastmessage bigint,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (roomid, createdat)
);

CREATE TABLE messages(
    roomid text,
    bucket int,
    messageid bigint,
    authorid text,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY ((hash, roomid), messageid)
);
```

On startup the client requests all rooms for a given user. I expect at some point, that a user will be member of hundreds of channels. So I only want to retrieve the last X active channels to reduce traffic.

Currently the room stores the last messageid (snowflake including timestamp) so I am capable to sort, after retrieving all rooms.

What changes are necessary to only load the last X active rooms from Cassandra? I know that I need to denormalize the structure somehow, but I do not know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a variation of your question in [#68782996](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68782996/) where I suggested creating this table for your app query "give me all rooms for a user":

```
CREATE TABLE rooms_by_userid (
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (userid, roomid)
)
```

From your description, it sounds like the app query is "give me the 10 most recent rooms by a user". You also mentioned that you are determining the most recent rooms using the `messageid`. In this case, the table would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE rooms_by_userid_by_messageid (
   userid text,
   messageid bigint,
   roomid text,
   ...
   PRIMARY KEY (userid, messageid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (messageid DESC, roomid ASC)
```

The data in this table would be partitioned by user ID and would contain rows sorted by message ID in reverse order (most recent first) where each message has an associated rooms. You would retrieve the 10 most recent rooms using `LIMIT 10` like this:

```
SELECT roomid FROM rooms_by_userid_by_messageid
  WHERE userid = ?
  AND messageid = ?
  LIMIT 10;
```

The important point here is that the data is already sorted in the order you need so you don't need to do any client-side sorting when you get the results from the database. Cheers!

Comment: Same question as on Rami Del Toro solution. 
The messageid in rooms_by_userid_by_messagid is updated on every new message in this room. So sequence looks something like "new message -> insert into message table ->for every member of the room update lastmessageid in rooms_by_userid_by_messageid".
This means a new message causes MEMBERS time new rows in the table. 
Wouldn't this be a lot of junk ? 
How should I handle the old/ redundant rows ? 
Thanks in advance Ramirez !

Comment: Well, the thing is that in Cassandra we have to design a table that would match each query because it's not RDBMS -- you choose C* because you have a requirement for super-fast queries at internet scale. If you don't need the old entries, you can certainly apply a TTL on them. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Create another table

```
CREATE TABLE user_active_channels (
   userid text,
   time bigint,
   room text,
   PRIMARY KEY (userid, time))
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC);
```

Each time a user joins a room , save the data in this table.
Then query like:

```
SELECT room FROM user_active_channels
 WHERE userid='The users Id' AND time > 0 limit 5;
```

Since the clustering column is time, the data is ordered by descending order on the partition, so the first 5 records will be the records that have the largest time, hence the latest user's active room and to avoid retrieving all the data, you can limit the query to only return the first 5 records.

Comment: I have some considerations on your answer. Time would be a clustering key right ? So I wouldn't be able to update the column, instead i have to insert a new row. Just for clarification I update the time col when a new message is posted to the room by any user, so a lot of junk is generated. 
Even when I delete the old row after inserting the new one, i would generate a lot of tombstones. 
Is your way still best practice for cassandra or would you suggest something else ? 
Thank you !

Comment: @lehmo Correct, you will need to insert data for each activity the user will do, effectively, you are tracking the user, which would result in a lot of data. As you are designing the system, you will decide the tradeoffs you will need to make. For example, to reduce data, maybe you track every minute, instead of every single message. Tombstones are another factor, you can configure the gc_grace_seconds or keep only recent data and compress older data. There are many ways to tackle this. With Cassandra, sorting and ranges, this is the standard, as Erick answered as well.